# Background Image Fix - Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

Hi guys I have started learning web development like a month ago and I am having difficulties with background images not showing properly on mobile devices.

I am using the below template and even this template is having the same problem.

The problem is simply the background images are zooming in on mobile instead proportionate it to the screen size accordingly.

I have tried media queries and even though its Bootstrap 3 i still could not figure it out.

http://piksell.diamondcreative.net/onepage.html

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try to use background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed;

Comment: Already tried :/ not working

Comment: try to alter your header elements style like the below..
element.style {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("img/home_01.jpg");
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

Comment: hope the styles (...background-attachment:fixed) used in styles are overriding by your script, check element style..

Comment: Thanks alot!!!!    -   style { background-attachment: fixed; background-image: url("img/home_01.jpg"); background-position: 50% 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%; }                                      - This one helped but i had to change the background-size to 100% 10%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to alter your header elements style like the below.. hope the styles (...background-attachment:fixed) used in styles are overriding by your script, check element style..

```
element.style { 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-image: url("img/home_01.jpg"); 
    background-position: 50% 0; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
}
```